# Recursive set that contains in a way all the other recursive ones?

Tags: logic, computability

I am wondering, whether there a exists a recursive set $S\subseteq \mathbb{N}^2$, such that for every recursive set $T \subseteq \mathbb{N} \ \exists c \in \mathbb{N}: \ T=\left\{n \in  \mathbb{N }| (c,n) \in S\right\}$ ?
(And by "recursive set" I mean one whose characteristic function is recursive)

I know a similar proposition holds, if we replace "recursive with "recursively enumerable", but somehow I can't figure this one out...

Comment: I assume you mean $(c,n)\in S$? Otherwise you don't use $S$ at all.

Comment: You may want to think about universal Turing machines.

Comment: And how sure are you about recursive?

Comment: I am so sorry - being tired I confused "recursive" with "recursively enumerable" and asked a wrong question: It should have been "recursive" everywhere I wrote "recursive enumerable" - I edited the question now, so that it is really what I was asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $c_A$ be a natural number that corresponds to any effective coding (for example: a Turing machine) of a recursively enumerable set $A$ and consider $S = \bigcup_A \{c_A\} \times A$.

---

The answer to your modified question is: no. Let us try to imitate the usual liar paradox. Suppose, that there exists a total Turing machine $U$ that computes $S$. And consider another Turing machine: $$N(x) = \mathit{not}\; U(x, x)$$
By the closure property $N$ is also recursive. So, there is a natural number $c_N$ corresponding to $N$ under $U$. Let us see what we get by applying $N$ to itself: $$N(c_N) = \mathit{not}\; U(c_N, c_N) = \mathit{not}\; N(c_N)$$
where the first equality is the definition of $N$ and the second holds by the definition of $S$.

Comment: This is an example of a more general phenomenon: universal sets exist for the non-self-dual complexity classes (e.g. $\Sigma^0_1$ = r.e.), but not the self-dual ones (e.g. $\Delta^0_1$ = recursive). And this holds in descriptive set theory, too (replace "complexity class" with "pointclass").